# Async Functions taking long when using Dispatch Group

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, grand-central-dispatch

I am using Firebase Storage to store my app's users' profile pictures, of which they can have up to six. So, whenever a user saves their images, I create a `DispatchGroup` and simultaneously delete all previously associated photoUrls in Firebase Storage and upload the new images to Firebase Storage. The user object in Firebase Database is also updated. I imagine this is an issue with the way I am implementing `DispatchGroup`, so I'll provide pseudocode of how I'm using it:

```swift
//PSEUDOCODE
func buttonPressed() {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    for url in oldUrl {
        group.enter()
        asyncFuncThatDeletesImage(at: url) {
            group.leave()
        }
    }

    for image in newImages {
        group.enter()
        asyncFuncThatUploadsNewImage(image) {
            group.leave()
        }
    }

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        //continue
    }
}
```

My async functions (`asyncFuncThatDeletesImage` and `asyncFuncThatUploadsNewImage`) **individually take a couple seconds at most to execute. When using my `DispatchGroup`, however, `.notify` is not being called until about 2 minutes have passed**.

Here is the full code for anybody interested:

```swift
@IBAction func saveButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let oldUrls = parentVC.photoUrls
    activityIndicator.isHidden = false
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    let photoUploader = PhotoUploader()
    var data = [Data]()
    var urls: [Int:String] = [:]

    let group = DispatchGroup()
    for oldUrl in oldUrls {
        group.enter()
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: oldUrl)

        //Removes image from storage
        storageRef.delete { error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                group.leave()
            } else {
                // File deleted successfully
                print("File deleted, took \(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 - startTime) seconds")
                group.leave()
            }
        }
    }

    for (index,image) in imagesArray.enumerated() {
        group.enter()
        let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)!
        data.append(imageData)
        photoUploader.upload(image: image, to: "Users/\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)/photoUrls/\(index)", completion: {(url, error) in
            if error == nil {
                urls[index] = url
                group.leave()

                print("Image uploaded, took \(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 - startTime) seconds")
            } else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                group.leave()
            }
        })
    }

    for i in imagesArray.count...6 {
        Database.database().reference().child("Users/\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)/photoUrls/\(i)").removeValue()
    }

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        //Do whatever I need to do
    }
```

Here is the function in my `PhotoUploader` class:

```swift
func upload(image: UIImage, to firebasePath: String, completion: @escaping (String?, Error?) -> Void) {
    //... creates data from the image...
    var data = NSData()
    // data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8)! as NSData
    data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)! as! NSData
    //...sets the upload path
    let filePath = "\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)\(String.randomStringWithLength(len: 20))" // path where you wanted to store img in storage
    let metaData = StorageMetadata()
    metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"

    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(filePath)
    storageRef.putData(data as Data, metadata: metaData){(metaData,error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        } else {
            storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                //Returns the url string to the newly uploaded image so that we can set the user's photoURL database property to this string
                Database.database().reference().child(firebasePath).setValue(url!.absoluteString)
                completion(url!.absoluteString, nil)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that you're putting the `notify` on the `.main` queue. Or that your `async` functions shouldn't be on the `.main` queue. Either way, I would make an independent `.concurrent` queue and put your `async` calls and the `notify` on that. i.e.

```
let customQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "customQueue", attributes: .concurrent)
```

...

```
func asyncFuncThatUploadsNewImage(image){
    customQueue.async{ ... }
}
func asyncFuncThatDeletesImage(image){
    customQueue.async{ ... }
}
```

...

```
group.notify(queue: customQueue) {
    //continue
}
```

It looks to me like you're using DispatchGroup correctly.

Putting things on the main queue is different from a custom queue for a few reasons, one of which is that it is a serial, not concurrent, queue, and also (I think) that other things could be running on the main queue that you're not aware of, which complicates the reasoning you have to do.

**Edit from OP**
The suggested edit worked, though I'm not entirely sure why. Also, within the `group.notify(queue:)` method, even though I passed the custom queue, I then had to wrap the enclosed code on the main thread. Its interesting, but here's the code that works:

```swift
@IBAction func saveButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let oldUrls = parentVC.photoUrls
    activityIndicator.isHidden = false
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    let photoUploader = PhotoUploader()
    var data = [Data]()
    var urls: [Int:String] = [:]

    //Custom queue
    let customQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "customQueue", attributes: .concurrent)
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    for oldUrl in oldUrls {
        group.enter()
        customQueue.async {
            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: oldUrl)

            //Removes image from storage
            storageRef.delete { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                    group.leave()
                } else {
                    // File deleted successfully
                    print("File deleted, took \(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 - startTime) seconds")
                    group.leave()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (index,image) in imagesArray.enumerated() {
        group.enter()
        customQueue.async {
            let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)!
            data.append(imageData)
            photoUploader.upload(image: image, to: "Users/\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)/photoUrls/\(index)", completion: {(url, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    urls[index] = url
                    group.leave()

                    print("Image uploaded, took \(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 - startTime) seconds")
                } else {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription)
                    group.leave()
                }
            })
        }
    }

    for i in imagesArray.count...6 {
        Database.database().reference().child("Users/\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)/photoUrls/\(i)").removeValue()
    }

    group.notify(queue: customQueue) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //Do whatever I need to do
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sweet, lemme try this out and let you know how it works.

Comment: “It might be that you're putting the notify on the `.main` queue.” ... If that’s really the problem, you should figure what’s blocking the main thread. So, go ahead and try this for diagnostic purposes, but this isn’t likely to be the right final solution. Instead, make sure you’re never blocking the main thread.

Comment: It think in this case it would be his own async calls holding up the main thread, since it's a serial queue they have to finish before anything else can happen. In effect, they're .sync calls, not .async calls.